# Full-width Image in a ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I am trying to have an image inside a ScrollView taking the full width of the screen while keeping its aspect ratio (I don't want a fixed background image). The answers in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/950 seem to work for a View but not a ScrollView.

The null width/height trick just makes the image disappear. Setting the width using `Dimensions.get('window').width` does not work for some reason; it leaves some space either on the top and bottom or the left and right of the image depending on its aspect ratio.

I can't use `Image.getSize()` as the image is local and would rather avoid hard-coding the dimensions as I have many other images that need to be styled this way. I have tried many other combinations of `flex`, `alignSelf`, etc. but none seem to work.

Comment: If you know that all images have the same aspect ratio, you can calculate it the following way:
`const imageHeight = imageWidth / aspectRatio;` or using the 0.40 new style attribute: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/5850165795c54b8d5de7bef9f69f6fe6b1b4763d

I had the same problem but I was using remote images so I managed to do it using `getSize` and calculating dimensions by myself. Couldn't find any other solution.

Comment: No they don't all have the same aspect ratio, which is why I said I wanted to avoid hard-coding it.

Comment: The image component doesn't resize itself based on image aspect ratio. So you have to get image size and do some calculation. That's not the same as hardcoding the dimensions. I guess you can then use the aspectRatio style on each image component. Before RN 0.40 I built my own component that could resize itself inside `onLayout` based on image aspect ratio. If aspectRatio style doesn't work, or you cannot use 0.40, I can share my code with you.

Comment: So regardless of the method used I will have to calculate all the aspect ratios beforehand?

Answer (score 2):

Setting ScrollView's `style={{width: "100%"}}` works for me.